# ChartJS - show tooltip on point hover, rather than gridline hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have implemented a chartjs linechart, works really really well. Is there anyway to restrict the tooltips to only appear when you hover each point of the line? At the moment the tool tips appear when hovering the whole vertical graph line.

I've been able to limit the hit detection on the X-axis using `pointHitDetectionRadius`
however i need to be able to limit the hit detection to just the point on the line.

anyone worked with the same issue?

- this is my Chart JS initialisation script, with a bunch of options set...

`$lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartjsData, {
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleShowLabels:false,
        bezierCurve : false,
        pointDotRadius : 8,
        datasetFill : false,
        animation: true,
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleSteps : 5,
        scaleStepWidth : 1,
        scaleStartValue : 0,
        responsive: true,
        showTooltips: true
    });
}, this));`

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: It's better to add it in the main question.

Comment: whoops - new to Stack Overflow ;)